# Ошибка E/SQLiteLog: (1) при работе с SugarORM на API23

Tags: android, sugarorm

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста где искать причину ошибки SugarORM на Api 23, такой же код работает стабильно на api 19 Есть предположение что, что-то с правами...
Класc для работы с БД

```
public class DBGroup extends SugarRecord {
    String name;
    int countNew;
    int countAll;

    public DBGroup(MyArrayGroup myArrayGroup) {
        this.name = myArrayGroup.getName();
        this.countNew = myArrayGroup.getCountNew();
        this.countAll = myArrayGroup.getCountAll();
    }

    public DBGroup() {
    }
}
```

В Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("IKNOW", "onCreate from MainActivity");

        DBGroup db = new DBGroup(new MyArrayGroup(0,"Tester",0,false,0));
        db.save();
}
```

**LOG**:

```
09-26 13:40:24.773 22993-22993/com.ivanowsoftware.us.iknov2 I/IKNOW: onCreate from MainActivity
09-26 13:40:24.785 22993-22993/com.ivanowsoftware.us.iknov2 E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
09-26 13:40:24.797 546-870/? I/logserver: extract_appname, forward search, appname=com.ivanowsoftware.us.iknov2
09-26 13:40:24.798 546-870/? I/logserver: get_fault_appname, appname=com.ivanowsoftware.us.iknov2
09-26 13:40:24.799 546-869/? I/logserver: handle_notify_event, send msg [submit:trigger=0,bugtype=2,modulename=com.ivanowsoftware.us.iknov2,level=1,testtype=NORMAL,path=/data/log/unzip/EVA-L19_EVA-L19C10B170_0000000000_20160926134024_crash,mode=1;]
09-26 13:40:24.815 22993-22993/com.ivanowsoftware.us.iknov2 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22993 SIG: 9
```

часть **manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
    <meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="iknov.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="1" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="com.ivanowsoftware.us.iknov2" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Буду благодарен за любую информацию, заранее спасибо!

Comment: дополнение - лог ошибки: [копия экрана с ошибкой здесь](http://c2n.me/3CCJbt1)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Снял галку с Instant RUN]
В манифесте сменил версию БД, Сделала Rebuil и все заработало!